# Session issues accessing Apache Tomcat application beyond a Proxy

Tags: session, tomcat, proxy

We have a application running on Apache Tomcat. When the application is accessed from beyond a proxy, the session information is getting lost or the user is logged out after some time. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost sounds like your proxy is not carrying the cookies over when it forwards HTTP requests.  Perhaps there's an over-zealous security setting on your proxy?